# Finding position of character within string in Spatialite?

Tags: spatialite

I have a bunch of data generated as a .dbf by ArcMap that I imported in Spatialite for processing.

One of the columns (text data) is of critical importance since it contains the ID of a point and a second ID of another point separated by a dash: `54 - 145` for instance.

What I need is to be able to extract the number that is before the "-". In order to do this, [I found about](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_corefunc.html) the `instr(X, Y)` function wihch should be able to locate the position of the "-":

> The instr(X,Y) function finds the first occurrence of string Y within string X and returns the number of prior characters plus 1, or 0 if Y
>   is nowhere found within X.

After this, `substr(X,Y,Z)` should be enough to get only the first number. It should be noted that the length of the first number ranges from one to six digits, extracting the substring based on a constant length is this not possible.

> The substr(X,Y,Z) function returns a substring of input string X that begins with the Y-th character and which is Z characters long.

After several tests, it seems that `instr(X,Y)` [does not exist in Spatialite](http://www.gaia-gis.it/spatialite-3.0.0-BETA/spatialite-sql-3.0.0.html). **Does anyone know about a function similar to instr(X,Y) in Spatialite?**

(I am using Spatialite-GUI 1.6.0 with Spatialite 4.0.0).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spatialite-gui 1.7.1 for Windows does come with enough recent SQLite (v.3.7.17)

```
select instr("name",'m') as location;
location
========
3
```

Comment: You are right, the problem came from a deprecated version of Spatialite-gui. I always have a hard time finding the URL of the precompiled newest release. For those interested, it's there: http://www.gaia-gis.it/gaia-sins/windows-bin-amd64/

Comment: In addition, given that ´Name´ is the column where I want to extract the ID, the following command does the job: ´trim(Substr("Name", 0, Instr("Name","-")))´